# Initialize module only once on imports from multiple files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have multiple python scripts, like this:

- utils.py
- module1.py
- module2.py
- module3.py
- main.py
- ...

In utils.py:

```py
import some_lib
role_id = "some_key_1"
secret_id = "some_key_2"

def initialize():
    real_key = some_web_request(role_id, secret_id)
    some_lib.init(real_key)

# define some other functions using some_lib
```

In module1.py, module2.py, module3.py:

```py
import utils

# define some other functions using functions in utils.py
```

In main.py:

```py
import module1
import module2
import module3

# do something
```

I want to run utils.initialize() only once for initializing `some_lib`. However, due to how `import` works in python, if I put initialize() on global area in utils.py then it will run on every import statement run.

I can implement this like this, in utils.py

```py
import some_lib

initialized = False

def initialize():
    # same as above

if not initialized:
    initialize()
    initialized = True
```

Is this a good practice? Is there better or elegant way to implement this?

Comment: "However, due to how `import` works in python, if I put initialize() on global area in utils.py then it will run on every import statement run" - that is not how `import` works.

Comment: @user2357112 If I import a module (not `from module import something`, just simple `import module`), the interpreter executes everything in the file. This is what I know about how `import` works. Is this wrong?

Comment: The first time you try to import a module or any of its contents, whether or not you use `from`, Python runs the module's code to initialize it. Further imports do not reexecute the module's code.

Comment: @user2357112 Oh, I misunderstood `import`! Then, I don't need to consider multiple execution of global area code in util. Thanks for your answer!